# 'Annotation' obbject is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm playing around with some soccer data and am trying to make a video of the players moving on the field with their numbers. I've got the players moving, but can't seem to figure out the numbers. I've tried a few things, and most recently this:

```
objs, = ax.plot(homex,homey,color=hcolorv,marker='o',linestyle="",MarkerSize=PlayerMarkerSize,alpha=PlayerAlpha)
figobjs.append(objs)
objs, = ax.plot(awayx,awayy,color=acolorv,marker='o',linestyle="",MarkerSize=PlayerMarkerSize,alpha=PlayerAlpha)
figobjs.append(objs)
            # if include_player_velocities:
            #   ax.quiver(homex,homey,homes['speed']) We need to break velocities into x and y components
            # if annotate:
            #   ax.text(homex+.5,homey+.5,homes['number'],fontsize=10,color=homecolor)
if annotate:
    for x,y in zip(homex,homey):
        label = list(homes['number'])
        objs, = ax.annotate(label,(x,y),textcoords="offsetpoints",xytext=(0,0),ha='center')
```

Also, this is what some of those items look like:

```
homex
Output: [0.17, 9.06, 19.85, 7.83, 45.18, 0.08, 0.01, 14.55, 19.59, 1.07, 17.25]
homey
Output: [-10.34, 0.97, 4.48, -5.31, 0.22, -22.02, 9.12, 22.68, -3.91, 19.52, -18.88]
list(homes['number'])
Output: [9, 22, 5, 27, 1, 8, 10, 4, 15, 11, 3]
```

I'm getting this error, though: "TypeError: 'Annotation' object is not iterable" Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax.annotate` returns an instance of class `Annotation`.
You call it as `objs, = ax.annotate(...)`. That comma after `objs` makes Python want to destructure `Annotation` as a list of items and take the first item.

tl;dr: you probably don't need the comma after `objs`.